# Generate names for a list of objects from that list

Tags: r

Can a list of unnamed objects be used to generate names for the objects in that list? Specifically, can I iterate over a list of lists to create a list of key/value pairs where the key is the object name for that list? Essentially, I want to go from `list( l1, l2, l3 )`  to  `list( l1=l1, l2=l2, l3=l3)` without calling `list()` and manually building the list. My end goal is to be able to iterate over a list of ggplot objects and use the object name as the file name for image exports.

I have tried lapply using `deparse(substitute(x))` with an anonymous function, but that just outputs the function's blank.

```
l1 <- list("a", "b", "c")
l2 <- list("g", "h", "i")
l3 <- list("x", "y", "z")


l_all <- list(l1,l2,l3)
lapply(l_all, function(x) {
  deparse(substitute(x))
}
)
```

I tried to use a loop to create a second list to hold the names, but the output is the iterator variable in string form.

```
l_all_2 <- list()
for(i in 1:length(l_all)){
  l_all_2[[i]] <- deparse(substitute(l_all[[i]]))
} 
l_all_2
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if someone has an idea or just the more R-ish way to do this I'd be grateful! Thanks for your time.

Comment: `mget(c("l1","l2","l3"))` ? Seems to check out - `identical(mget(c("l1","l2","l3")), list(l1=l1, l2=l2, l3=l3))` gives `TRUE`

Comment: Chinsoon- something like that, but I want to return the object name of the list, rather than the elements in the list.

Comment: Thelatemail- that is more or less it, thanks! Is the caveat that I just need to start with a list of strings?

Comment: Chinsoon- yep that's bang on once they have names. Thanks!

Comment: it will only work if you already have `l1` `l2` `l3` existing as floating objects. Otherwise `l_all` has no knowledge of what its parts are called.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the help!